# AWS RDS Write I/O is really high

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is this way too high?  How can we improve this?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

IOPS is a difficult metric to 'improve'; unless you are in control of the code that's hammering your disk and can optimize its disk access patterns, there's not much you can do with this. Many IOPS typically equates to heavy system usage for a database or web server - which isn't necessarily a bad problem to have. Is there a reason you want to bring this number down?

Answer (score 1):

We had a very large database in their biggest RDS instance and just got hammered with large IO spikes.. We just moved off RDS to a EC2 instance and things got better.

Comment: interesting, can you share more details?

Comment: I'm not sure if its the same as it was many years ago.. but it RDS use to be on EBS so large IO operations would be bad. Moving to local disk sped things up alot

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the slow query log or general log doing lots of writes? [See here](http://www.forlinux.co.uk/expertise/blog/2012/02/13/amazon-rds-high-disk-usage-logs/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.